# Update Vue route param dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a multilingual Vue (Nuxt) app. Based I'm setting the selected language / locale in the URL, e.g. `http://www.example.net/sv-SE/somepage`.

The routes are registered with an optional iso code: `/:iso_code([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})?/somepage`. This all works as intented.

Now to my question: I have a language dropdown where the user can set the desired language. Is there any way to update the route param `iso_code` above, without resorting to `history.replaceState`?

I've tried the router API, without success. The URL isn't updated, i.e. if the URL is `http://www.example.net/sv-SE/somepage`, `sv-SE` isn't replaced with `en-US` when running the code:

```
this.$router.replace({ path: this.$route.fullPath, params: { iso_code: 'en-US' } })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To push a route with the `params` object, you should use a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html):

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/:iso_code([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})?/somepage',
    name: 'somepage',
    //...
  }
]
export default new VueRouter({ routes })
```

Then, you'd `$router.push` the route's `name` along with `params`:

<sup>*App.vue:*</sup>

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'somepage', params: { iso_code: 'sv-SE' }}">sv-SE</router-link>

    <button @click="$router.push({ name: 'somepage', params: { iso_code: 'es-SP' }})">es-SP</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo of named route](https://codesandbox.io/embed/quizzical-leakey-t3sl0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Additionally, you could update the `params` of the current route by pushing only the `params` object (i.e., without a `path` or `name`). For example, assuming that `path`/`name` are already at the correct route to receive the `iso_code` parameter, you could `$router.push({ params: { iso_code: 'es-SP' }})`:

<sup>*SomePage.vue:*</sup>

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ iso_code }}</div>
    <button @click="$router.push({ params: { iso_code: 'es-SP' }})">es-SP</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo of params update for current route](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pushing-route-with-params-lj1j2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fviews%2FSomePage.vue&theme=dark)

---

If you preferred not to use named routes, you'd have to push the fully resolved path (e.g., `/sv-SE/somepage`) and no `params`:

```
this.$router.push('/sv-SE/somepage')
```

The disadvantage in this case is you'd have to update this reference if you ever decide to change the path.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed it also seems to work with only params? e.g. `this.$router.push({ 
params: { iso_code: 'sv-SE' } })`

Comment: Oh, nice. I wasn't aware that could be done.

Comment: Does it still work? I'm using a rather old version of the router. If it does, please update the answer

Comment: @Johan It still works, but requires the current route to accept the `iso_code` param (i.e., the current route must be `somepage`). See updated answer.